# Incorrect "questions per day" for beta sites on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The "Questions Per Day" calculation for beta sites seems to be broken, at least for the new Travel site. I first noticed this when the private beta launched, but I thought it was due to the partial first day or something. However, a few days later, it's still wrong.

If we look at the [Area 51 entry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel) for it, we see 2 days in beta, 7.7 questions per day:

[image: Area51 site]

If we then hop over to the beta site, we see we're now up to 108 questions (and I think we were probably at about 80 or so at midnight):

[image]

So, it seems that the questions per day calculation is somehow broken for beta sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed -- we now only show questions per day since the beta began, or over the past two weeks (whichever is shorter).

Answer (score 4):

If you hover your cursor over the number, you'll see that it's the average over two weeks.

Comment: But as the site's only been going 2 days, so a 2 week value doesn't make any sense, especially as there's a target!

Comment: @Gagravarr: On the other hand, averaging over the first two days wouldn't make sense either, since the number of questions the first day is usually much higher other days.

Comment: A high average on the first few days would make sense to me, if there are lots of questions those days! Maybe skipping showing a figure for a week would be the answer then, if it's hard coded to check a fortnight and initial days are volatile?

Comment: As that parameter is used to decide if the site is going fine, it makes sense to calculate (or extrapolate) the average number of questions for two weeks.

Comment: Interesting - it's just changed to the last 7 days for the Travel SE private Beta...